# Java NumberFormatException pops up for 101836849?

Tags: java, exception, integer

Why is this happening with an integer string that I want to convert to integer?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "101836849"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Are you using the parseInt(String s, int radix) method ?

Comment: also check for control chars

Comment: You do not need any  parse if you want to convert from integer to String!

Comment: please draft full stack question.

Comment: I need string to integer conversion. My code says Integer.parseInt("101836849")

Comment: The full stack has 1 more exception that I would not want to show but I got the answers. Thank you all who participated in getting the answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your number string `"101836849"` has the character &#65279 (ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE) at index 0. This character is rejected by `Integer.parseInt`.

Verify this by printing the string chars:

```
for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    System.out.println((int)s.charAt(i));
```

Comment: I can parse it just fine with the default radix of 10.

Comment: @Terje you need to copy the exact string from the OP stacktrace (including the quotes) into your editor, in order to have this invisible character. Even Eclipse does not display it, but it is there.

Comment: Right, IDEA is showing it now. I didn't include the quotes earlier.

Comment: Yes you are right  that character seems its in my string.

Comment: @wero how does this come from?

Comment: @ErinAvllazagaj don't know - from where did you get the string? Non breaking spaces are used in digital typesetting to control layout. Or it could have been a byte order mark at the start of a file which was not treated correctly by the reading program. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word-joiner)