# How can i avoid this format exception despite trim

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

EDIT : hidden character mess'd with my editor.

I want to read from my text file and add objects to an array from it. I'm getting a

```
NumberFormatException: For input string : "2".
```

If I remove the first line of the file, I get a format exception for input string "3".

What am I missing there ?

```
ArrayList<Personne> listp = new ArrayList<Personne>();
try {
    FileReader file = new FileReader(personneFilePath);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] attributes = line.split(",");
        listp.add(new Personne(Integer.parseInt(attributes[0].trim()), attributes[1], attributes[2], Double.parseDouble(attributes[3]), attributes[4], attributes[5], attributes[6]));
    }
    file.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Erreur 1 : " + e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Erreur 2 : " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Here is the content of the file i'm reading;

```
2, Claire, Chazal, 65.0 , rue de Rennes, Laval, 53000
3, Jacques, Dupont, 90.0 , rue des Anges, Paris, 75000
4, Celine, Dia, 66.0 , rue Diderot, Paris, 75000
5, Remy, Cheval, 88.0 , rue du paradis, Nantes, 44000
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe your file contains some unprintable character(s) at start of file/rows which are not included in this question. Try printing length of `attributes[0]` and each character it holds. In Java 8 you could use `attributes[0].chars().forEach(System.out::println)`.

Comment: Your file probably has a Byte Order Mark character (`'\ufeff'`) at the beginning.  Copy the text into a text editor other than Notepad and save it from there.  You can also try adding `line = line.replaceAll("\ufeff", "");` after your call to nextLine.

Comment: Using a debugger, check the values of `attributes[0].trim()`, `attributes[3]`, `Integer.parseInt(attributes[0].trim())`, and `Double.parseDouble(attributes[3])`

Comment: probably something related to zero width characters in your input which are nevertheless rejected by `Integer.parseInt`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677934/java-numberformatexception-pops-up-for-101836849/34678100#34678100

Comment: Try to post the first variable of Personne class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It loosk like your file contains some unprintable characters near 2 which is not whitespace so `trim()` can't remove it.

To remove it you can use `replaceAll("\\D","")` instead of `trim()`.

Better preferred solution would be removing cause of this problem, so set up your editor/file format/encoding properly and stop placing these characters in your file.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks fine.

I would recommend using debug mode (IntelliJ or Eclipse work well for this) and stepping into the `Integer.parseInt` method to see what input it is getting or where it fails.

Alternatively, add a print statement to see the value of `attributes[0].trim()`, maybe also the length of the string. It seems like there may be a non-printable character.